# Rails Mass Assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, simple-form

I have a site that keeps track of SAT tutoring sessions. The curriculum that the students learn is a collection of rules. I have a model for each tutoring session called "Sittings" and the rules model is called "Rules". I want the site admin to be able to enter a Sitting by date, and then use checkboxes to select which "rules" the student got wrong in that sitting. I'm a little confused as to how I can create the form to pull out specific rules without adding attributes to my Sitting model of rule1, rule2, etc. I'm using simple_form to create my forms.

My Sitting model:

```
class Sitting < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :date, :comment, :rule_id, :user_id

validates :date, presence: true

belongs_to :user

has_many :combos
has_many :rules, :through => :combos

end
```

My Rules model:

```
class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :name, :subject, :session_id, :hint_id, :question_id, :trigger_id

validates :name, presence: true
validates :subject, presence: true

has_many :questions
has_many :triggers
has_many :hints
has_many :combos
has_many :sittings, :through => :combos

end
```

My Combo model:

```
class Combo < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :sitting
belongs_to :rule

end
```

Edit:

Here's what I have tried for the form. It does create the checkbox form, but my DB isn't updating the rule_id. (shows as nil when I create a Sitting)

form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@sitting, html: { class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <% Rule.all.each do |rule| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "sitting[rule_ids][]", rule.id, @sitting.rule_ids.include?(rule.id) %> <%= rule.id %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input :comment, as: :text, input_html: { rows: "2", :class => "form-control" }, label: "Comments:" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <%= f.date_select :date, as: :date, label: "Taken Date:" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I updated my strong params to allow an array:

```
def create
@sitting = Sitting.new(sitting_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @sitting.save
    format.html { redirect_to @sitting, notice: 'Sitting was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @sitting }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @sitting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def sitting_params
  params.require(:sitting).permit(:comment, :date, :user_id, :rule_id => [])
end
```

Am I missing something in order to update the Sitting.rule_id properly? I get the following error in my logs:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Sitting: rule_ids
app/controllers/sittings_controller.rb:27:in `create'
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Can you add your form code. and can you please be more specific what exactly you want to do .

Comment: Your `Rule` object seems to have trigger_id, hint_id and question_id columns; in which case it should `belong_to` those associated objects rather than `has_many` of them

Comment: PS you don't actually ask any question :-)

Comment: @pavling I'm sorry for not being more clear. I was asking how to create checkboxes to allow multiple rule_ids to be added to Sittings. I figured out some of it, but now the database isn't updating when I create a new Sitting. Please see my edit above. And thanks!

Comment: in your `permit` it must be `:rule_ids => []` (plural!)

Comment: @MarianTheisen Thanks for noticing that typo, but it's still not registering in the DB. I get the error that I added above.

Comment: Why do you have both `attr_accessible` and strong params in your code? 00 Anyway you need to apply Marian's suggestion there as well, but you shouldn't need those both features together.

Comment: @BroiSatse I didn't realize that. When I remove the attr_accessible from Sittings I get the following error: WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Sitting: comment, date(1i), date(2i), date(3i), rule_ids

Comment: @TonyTambe - This puzzles me. WHich rails version are you using? It is possible to install those features as additional gems.

Comment: @TonyTambe- Please check your Gemfile for `protected_attributes` gem.

Comment: @BroiSatse Yes, I have that there. I see what you're saying now. So I either remove that gem and move all of my attributes to strong params, or find another way to do the mass assignment, correct?

Comment: @TonyTambe - Well you can keep both of them if you want, but they do  exactly some thing except that strong_params are doing it better. :P

Comment: @BroiSatse Ok, I did all of that. I still get rule_id: nil when I create a new sitting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62050/discussion-between-broisatse-and-tony-tambe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to summarize what we got through over the chat.

Firstly, you do not need both `attr_accessible` and `strong_params` at the same time. I've posted [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954839/ror-active-record-undefined-method/25954893#25954893) some time ago explaining how those two approaches differs from each other.

You're running rails 4, so you should take advantage of strong params and not use protected_attributes gem. In short, remove this gem from you Gemfile as well as all `attr_accessible` calls.

As Marian noticed, you have a typo in your strong params method, you need to permit `rule_ids`, not `rule_id`. `rule_id` column is obsolete, as `sitting has_many :rules :through` rather than `sitting belongs_to :rule` - most likely it is an artifact of old association code.

As soon as rule_ids are assigned within your model, it will create new join models in your join table, creating an association between given sitting and passed rules.